# output differences when using findContours in opencv2 and opencv3

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.2

I am using the exact same steps to find the contours of an image but I am getting two different results in Opencv 2.4.8 and Opencv 3.2! Anybody knows why?
Here is the procedure:

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;

    cv::imwrite("binImageInB.jpg", binImageIn);

    // find contour of the binary image 
    cv::findContours( binImageIn, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0) ); // Find the contours in the image   // save

    cv::imwrite("binImageIn.jpg", binImageIn);
```

The input image is:

[image: Input Image]

The output when using opencv 2.4.8:

[image: Output Opencv2]

And the output when using Opencv3.2:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for 2.4.x](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) mentions:

> **Note:** Source image is modified by this function.

---

The [documentation for 3.3.1](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a) mentions:

> Since opencv 3.2 source image is not modified by this function.

---

In general, you use the `contours` and `hierarchy` output parameters. Since the later versions no longer modify the input image, I'd consided that a side effect, which was not intended to be useful.

Comment: This is confusing...I am using 3.2 and in the documentation, it does not mention anything is the input image is changed or not https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a

Comment: @Samer You're right. It seems they forgot to add that info to the documentaion comments in 3.2 and [fixed it later](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/e6f27240d5e5fc49f9d079a34abaccf2bee72654).